# Question about groups where generators are interchangable

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, free-groups

Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite group of rank 2 defined from generators $A$ and $B$.

For any element of $G$ defined by a word $W$, let the dual of that element be defined by a word $\overline{W}$, formed by replacing each of the letters $A$ and $B$ with the other, e.g.  $AABBAB$ becomes $BBAABA$.

If every valid equation relating elements remains true when the generating elements are swapped, that is $W=V\iff \overline{W}=\overline{V} $  (e.g. $ABB=BAAB \implies BAA=ABBA$, then what can be concluded about $G$?

Do such groups exist? and if so what is the order of their irreducible faithful matrix representation.

Comment: Yes, such groups exist. If $F$ is the free  group of rank $2$ generated by $x$ and $y$, and $N$ is any normal subgroup that is invariant under the automorphism of $F$ that exchanges $x$ and $y$, then $F/N$ will satisfy your condition. There are plenty of such normal subgroups.

Comment: What is your interest in this question? If you know any character theory (which would be relevant to the irreducible faithful matrix representation part) you surely know enough group theory to make more progress than this.

Comment: @MarkBennet My interest in this question comes from a question I have about linear algebra, and I was told I should reformulate it in terms of groups and their generators. I am interested to know the minimum order of matrix needed to represent such a group.
I have just opened the wikipedia page on character theory, and I'm wishing I'd found it hours ago.

Comment: I think there are far too many examples for it to be possible to say anything in general about the degree of their representations. For example, for any finite simple group it is possible to find $A$ and $B$ satisfying that condition.

Comment: I suggest that you bring your linear algebra question to the site, because there is likely some feature of it which has gone missing in your question/translation to the new context. Arturo and Derek have given an indication that there is unlikely to be a useful answer in the generality you are currently asking for.